# Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal - is this cmdlet deprecated?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, pnp-powershell, azure

Is **Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal** cmdlet deprecated?

I was able to use this cmdlet successfully 3 months before, but now ,running this cmdlet displays error that's this is not available.

when I run **Get-Command -Module PnP.Powershell** also, I don't get the cmdlet.

Comment: Hi @George, did you try below suggestions? Is it working for you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per the PnP PowerShell official documentation, the `Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal` cmdlet is not deprecated.

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal.html)

---

I think there is some version conflict in the PnP PowerShell modules/versions installed on your system. The current stable & latest of PnP PowerShell is `v2.2.0`.

Try below steps once:

1. Uninstall all versions of `SharePointPnPPowershellOnline` module from your system.
2. Uninstall all versions of PnP PowerShell modules from your system
3. Install the latest and stable version (`v2.2.0`) of PnP PowerShell by following below documentations

**Documentations**:

1. [Upgrading from the Legacy version of PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/upgrading.html)
2. [Installing PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html)